# Incrementing a string and retaining whatever amount of leading zeros there is

Tags: php, increment

How can I get this to work:

```
$q = '0004';

echo ++$q; // outputs 5 instead of 0005
```

$q is pulled from a db, and can have any amount of leading zeros, so I can't use str_pad or sprintf (unless I count the number of zeros, but that's messy if there is a simpler way)

Thanks!

Comment: So if the number is `0009` it will be `00010` on increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$q='1'.$q;
$q++;
$q= substr($q, 1);
```

I think it works.

**Edit**:
It will be a string.

Comment: Yes, it's not what I was expecting either, nice lateral thinking solution! Thanks!